# 'PFObject does not have a member named 'subscript'

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I can't seem to find anything to fix this, searched all over the internet. Could somebody please explain to me how to fix this? :)

```
  func refresh() {
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        self.messagesArray = [String]()

        if let objs = objects {
            for messageObject in objs {
                let messageText:String? = (messageObject as PFObject)["Text"] as? String >>>ERROR <<<
                if messageText != nil {
                    self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)
                }
            }
        }

        self.messageTableView.reloadData() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: are you using the new swift sdk with the old parse sdks , if yes we have to wait until parse release a new sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
let messageText:String? = messageObject.valueForKey("Text") as? String
```